# suppose I have a +1,000,000,000,000,000 entry in my database

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

So suppose I have +1,000,000,000,000,000 or more entries in my database! and I am looking for the entry number 1,999,999,999,999,990 wouldn't it take years to get it?

Now as a programmer, will I ever encounter such a situations? if so, what is the solution?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read about indexing, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work

Comment: Why would you be "looking for" the "entry number"? What do you mean by "entry number"?

Comment: What type of database? On what hardware?

Comment: If you've indexed column in your table, it should take a short amount of time.

Comment: There are too many unkown factors in your question that it's just impossible to answer it correctly. What type of database do you use? What is the size of one record so that you can store all of them? Is your data indexed (this case you might get the result almost immediately). ...

Comment: by indexing do you all mean an ID column? @MátéJuhász

Comment: Answer: You make sure to have an index for the field where the search criteria resides, i.e. it has to be SORTED.Then you use "binary search" (google it). With "n" items in the database, the MAXIMUM number of compare operations required is `int(log(n)/log(2)+1)` - i.e. `50` for n=1E+15 (as above)

Comment: thanks a lot @Hannu , shall you think there are some articles/methods/algorithms/DB scheme that helps let me know please :) thanks again.

Comment: => "Binary search"

Comment: Either your going to have to throw hardware at it, or subdivide it.  For example you could have daily,weekly,monthly, or yearly databases so no 1 database/table has that many records.  Index columns and partitioning may also help.  Otherwise you will need to have a system with a tons of M.2 SSD storage, and as many CPU/GPU as possible.  I think using one of the GPU accelerated DB is the best solutions.

Comment: The time required to look up a key in a SORTED database depends on the formula above, assuming a reasonably quick media to read from (i.e. comparable to a hardisk at least) - the answer is "no time".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very few people will encounter such a situation that severe. The solution is not a programming solution unless you write databases, but it is a software engineering problem. If this issue is encountered by most of us, the solution would be to use a new product (or more likely multiple products and updated infrastructure) that can handle that size.

If you are trying to future proof a new project, you are likely spending your time in the wrong place. All of the mega large data companies (think FaceBook or Google) have evolved their hardware and software over time to meet the needs. This makes sense because needs change and so do solutions.

As far the the time question, that is too broad, but FaceBook and Google have certainly solved that problem, but I doubt it was cheap. You aren't going to operate at this level without some serious engineering.

Comment: so there is no "open-source" solution out there for me?

Comment: @Jes there certainly is some open source software used for this sort of a problem, but it is not a silver bullet by itself. It requires techniques and hardware to accomplish. You should read some of the software engineering articles that these large companies put out.